# Show ListView item details in second Activity

Tags: android, android-layout

I have one `Activity` with a list of items. By clicking an item, it brings up a second `Activity` with details of the item clicked in the first `Activity`.

**My first activity:** (I am passing a `string[]` via `Intent`)

```
Bundle bundle= new Bundle();
bundle.putStringArray("item_details", new String[]{item_name, item_desc, item_date, item_loc}); 

Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), DataProductDetail.class);
intent.putExtras(extras);
```

**My second activity:** (receiving `string[]`)

```
 Bundle bundle = this.getIntent().getExtras();
 String[] itemArray = bundle.getStringArray("item_details"); 

 ArrayAdapter<String> itemArrayAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, R.layout.list_item, itemArray );

 ListView list = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.list);
        detailsList.setAdapter(itemArrayAdapter );
```

Layout of **list_item**:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<TextView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:padding="10dp"
    android:textSize="18sp"
    android:textColor="#0c2d63" />
```

**My Question/Problem:**

I want my first screen on the app to look like this (which is working):

```
item1
item2
item3
```

**Problem:**

The second screen when `item1` is clicked in the first `Activity` should be like this (not sure how to get this, above code doesn't work):

```
Name: xyz is "item_name" from array "itemArray" received from intent 
Description: This is the description from "item_desc" from array "itemArray"
Date: This is the date string grabbed from item_date from array "itemArray"
```

How can I get such a layout as shown in the second screen above? I want `Name, Description, Date` to be shown on the second screen and grab certain elements of an array into each for display as item details.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you asked here is an example of `layout xml` file for the second Activity:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal" >

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:text="Name: " />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/name"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="xyz is item_name from array itemArray received from intent" />

</LinearLayout>

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal" >

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:text="Description: " />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/description"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="This is the description from item_desc from array itemArray" />

</LinearLayout>

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal" >

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:text="Date: " />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/date"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="This is the date string grabbed from item_date from array itemArray" />

</LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

And the screenshot:

[image]

For the `TextViews` with `IDs` *name*, *description* and *date* you set text programmatically calling `setText()` method.

Of course, as it's just an example you might need to add some attributes for aligning the text etc.